# Prolog: Out of local stack error

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

Consider the following code (taken from *Introduction to Prolog* by RP Suri):

```
/* A set of father-child pairs declared */
father("Motilal", "Jawaharlal").
father("Motilal", "Vijayalakshmi").
father("Motilal", "Krishna").
father("Jawaharlal", "Indira").
father("Ranjit", "Tara").
father("Ranjit", "Lekha").
father("Ranjit", "Rita").
father("Feroz", "Sanjay").
father("Feroz", "Rajiv").
father("Sanjay", "Varun").
father("Rajiv", "Rahul").
father("Rajiv", "Priyanka").

/* Mothers declared */
wife_of("Swaruprani", "Motilal").
wife_of("Kamla", "Jawaharlal").
wife_of("Vijayalakshmi", "Ranjit").
wife_of("Indira", "Feroz").
wife_of("Maneka", "Sanjay").
wife_of("Sonia", "Rajiv").
wife_of("Priyanka", "Robert").

/* Predicates declared */
mother(M, C) :- wife_of(M, Hus) , father(Hus, C).

parent(P, C) :- mother(P, C) ; father(P, C).

ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Y) :- ancestor(X, Z) , parent(Z, Y).
```

Now if I query

```
ancestor("Motilal", X)
```

I get output as:

```
?- ancestor("Motilal", X).
X = "Jawaharlal" ;
X = "Vijayalakshmi" ;
.
.
.
X = "Priyanka" ;
```

(which is the correct output), after which the program stops and a few seconds later I get the message:

```
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

A similar thing happens when I query

```
ancestor(X, "Motilal").
```

This should return nothing, but the prompt again disappears for a few seconds followed by the same error message. What is the problem in the code?

Comment: Better use `'` in place of `"`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the problem in your code there is no need to look at your entire program. Instead it suffices to look at a tiny fraction that is responsible for non-termination:

```
?- ancestor(X, 'Motilal'), false.

ancestor(X, Y) :- false, parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Y) :- ancestor(X, Z) , false, parent(Z, Y).
```

This fragment already does not terminate, and thus the entire program does not terminate. No matter what you wrote in the other parts! So you need to change something in the remaining part. Otherwise, the error will persist.

For more see [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

Do you see what you need to change?

> Put the goal `parent(Z, Y)` in front!

BTW, it is common in Prolog to use single-quoted atoms in such a situation, since this is much more efficient!

Comment: I got to learn a lot, thanks! Also, if I am right, the difference between single quotes and double quotes is that single quotes are treated as atoms, while double quotes are treated as strings?

Comment: Single quotes are always atoms. Double quotes get their meaning from a Prolog flag `double_quotes`. They may be lists of characters, lists of character codes and atoms. SWI has "strings" as default - but this is specific to SWI only. And SWI handles them much less efficiently than atoms.